# mysql stored procedure regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, stored-procedures

i try to check my IN param with a regexp but always is a error

```
BEGIN
declare clausolein varchar(255);
IF POST_FARMS is null THEN
SET clausolein=1;
ELSE IF POST_FARMS REGEXP '^[1-9]' THEN
SET clausolein=2;
ELSE
SET clausolein=3;
END IF;
SELECT clausolein;
END
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: right syntax to use near ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please study thoroughly this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

> **13.6.5.2 IF Syntax**
>   
> IF search_condition THEN statement_list
>   
>    [**ELSEIF** search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>   
>    [ELSE statement_list]
>   
> END IF

and then please compare the above syntax with your code:

> **ELSE   IF**  POST_FARMS REGEXP '^[1-9]' THEN